# trouble creating python function to log into multiple email accounts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, selenium-webdriver

Below is code of me trying to figure out how to create a function that contains a list to log into each email after each loop it goes threw executing 1 email log in at a time! problem is it is trying to loop threw the whole list instead of 1 at a time, how can i write it to log into 1 email on the list execute rest of my main fuction then loop back to second item on list.

```
def login():


    email_group1 = ["*****","*****",""]
    pass_group1 = ["*****","*****",""]


#click login btn
    loginbtn1 = driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/section[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[2]")
    loginbtn1.is_displayed()
    loginbtn1.click()

# login email
    time.sleep(1)
    login_email = driver.find_element("name", "email")
    login_email.is_displayed()

    for email in email_group1:

        login_email.send_keys(email)


    login_pass = driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/input")
    login_pass.is_displayed()

    for password in pass_group1:

        login_pass.send_keys(password)
```

iv rewritten the code but im having trouble figuring out how to loop 1 item out of the list at a time!

Comment: "...Loop threw the whole list instead of 1 at a time" This is inaccurate. You are getting a syntax error. I recommend that you google it and you will quickly find an answer.

Comment: Even without the "list object is not callable" error, this code is entering **all** of the email address into one email input element, and then entering **all** the passwords into the password input element.  Surely that is not going to work.

Comment: thats precisely what im trying to prevent. i want to call 1 item from the list when it loops around call the next item on list, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward.

```
    email_group1 = ["*****","*****",""]
    ...
    for email in email_group1():
```

Trying to invoke that `list` as a function won't end well.

You wanted:

```
    for email in email_group1:
```

Comment: Simple typo errors like this generally don't warrant a formal answer.

Comment: thank you for advice. could u possible explain how i could loop threw 1 item on list per loop? i edited the program and it works only problem is it submits the whole list into the login_email = driver.find_element("name", "email") variable. my goal is to submit 1 thing from the list every time the loop happens.